# Adding support for a three column join in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, collection-select

I'm working on an application where we have a survey, and the survey can be run at multiple locations, and each location could have a different staff member.  Logically, makes sense to create a three column join table between Survey, Location, and Trainer.  Seems easy enough.

The problem I'm having is associating all three in the form when submitting.  I know how to create an array of locations and an array of staff members, but not clear on how to associate those two together.

Selecting both the locations and staff members is done through a collection select.

After that, I feel pretty comfortable I can write the necessary code to create the records in the join table, just looking for some ideas how to structure the HTML and/or form_for objects.